# Unity 2D Raycasting from a Rotating Transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I'm trying to create a vision field in Unity 2d. I'm projecting raycasts from a rotating gameobject which rotates according to where the character is looking. However this character moves back and forth so when they are moving left I set the transform.scale to -1. The problem is when I do this the raycasts don't change direction along with the character and stay pointing right! Here is the code, I'm probably missing something obvious! Any help would be appreciated!

```
        Transform parent;
    float vision_angle_ = 50;
    float direction;
    Vector3 angle;
    Vector2 position;
    Quaternion q;
    int x = 10;

    void Start ()
    {
            parent = transform.parent;
    }

    void Update ()
    {

            direction = parent.GetComponent<Behaviour>().direction;

            angle = new Vector2 (x, Mathf.Tan ((vision_angle_) * .5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * x);
            q = Quaternion.AngleAxis (1, -transform.forward);       
            position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

            for (float i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    angle = q * angle;
                    RaycastHit2D tile_hit = Physics2D.Raycast (position, transform.TransformDirection (angle), 10);
                    Debug.DrawRay (position, transform.TransformDirection (angle), Color.green);
            }       

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TransformDirection](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) doesn't take the scale of your transform into account. You can adjust to compensate:

```
Vector2 direction = transform.TransformDirection(angle);
if (transform.localScale.x < 0f) {
    direction.x = -direction.x;
}

RaycastHit2D tile_hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, 10);
```